# connectionstring with windows username and password, can we?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can we use windows AD username and password in connection string ? will it work? Users wants to use their AD account to get data from sql server.

Comment: Do you mean use Integrated Security=SSPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do this, you can use impersonation to connect to the SQL server using the user that the client is logged in as.

If you configure the application in IIS to require Windows Authentication, and then in your connection string use `Integrated Security=true;` - then you'll get the permissions of the logged in user when you hit the database from your ASP.Net application.

Comment: does application needs enter any login credential for this? What will be the application pool identity for this?

Comment: @James123 Yes, in this case you need to have a login from the IIS so the user pass his credentials. But you can normally configure your clients in company LAN's that you single sign on pass your username/password in the intranet zone.

Comment: There should be an 'impersonate' identity. The user will be prompted for their login details when they visit the site (or if they use Internet Explorer, it'll automatically use the credentials of the logged in user in certain circumstances)

Comment: What will be the application pool identity for this? does it need any service account to use it?

Comment: The application pool will take the identity of the logged in user if you set it up to use impersonation.

Comment: I just done what you said.. getting "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." will client computer and deployed application needs to me in same domain? client computer domain is "companyHQ" and deployed on "companyInside", Both are trusted each other Trusted Domains.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot specify windows account credentials in SQL connection string. You can only specify that the SQL connection will use the integrated security and that will be whoever is executing the code (the application pool identity).

An alternative is to use impersonation. Depending on your application you might set that up in IIS (resulting in all code executing under the privileges of the authenticated user) or impersonate the user manually in code using their username and password as shown on [`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) MSDN page.